# Water grey levels - remote sensing

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, noaa

[image: NOAA AVHRR satellite image]

by viewing two bands in erdas imagine the grey levels of the water differ.  on the one image as below the water is dark and the other image the water is light.  why is that?  what cause the difference?

Comment: What two bands? I suspect that one is infra red and the other may be visible (red, green or blue).

Comment: I suspect this is a bit depth related problem, but some more details would be helpful.  What steps did you use to produce the posted image?  What sensor? Band combos?  What is the pixel bit depth?